# How to Make Blog Title Unique to User?

Tags: django, django-models

I was wondering how to enforce that the blog post title created by a user does not match the name of any other blog posts created by that user.

Here is my models.py, as I think this is where it should go, but I can add any other files as needed. Thanks in advance for any tips.

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/') #todo: validate size or resize here
    # ... edited out some fields for SO post
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            #new item object, setting slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Item, self).save()
```

Comment: You can use `unique_together`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [**`unique_together`** constraint [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) here:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'name']]

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            #new item object, setting slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Item, self).save()
```

It thus means that a 2-tuple that contains the `user_id` and the `name` should be unique. This thus means that the same `name` can be used for a different `user`, or a different `name` can be used for the same `user`, but not the same `name` for the same `user`. If this is the only `unique_together` constraint you want to add, you can write this as `unique_together = ['user', 'name']` as well.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. Waiting the 10 mins before I can accept your answer!

Comment: I keep getting `'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'user_id'.` I am using a custom user model, and I've changed my code to use get_user_model() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Jake1986: sorry, it should be `user`, not `user_id`.

Comment: No worries! Thanks - that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django 2.2 you can use `UniqueConstraint` instead of `unique_together` like this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'name'], name='some_name')
    ]
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) state:

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.